# What should I do with the $C = KC_0$ equation given this situation?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

We've been asked to graph a Dielectric Constant (x) and Capacitance (y) graph from 9 laboratory trials (with $\varepsilon_0 = 8.85\frac{F}{m}$,  $A=200.3mm^2$, and $d=8.1mm$) and find its slope (which we got, m = 0.22). Beforehand, the instructions also told us to determine $C_{0}$ = $\frac{\varepsilon_{0} A}{d} = 0.2188 pF$, but we rounded it off to $0.22pF$.

---

Now that we already have the results from the 9 trials, we are being asked to use this equation below to determine $C_0$ again:
$$C=KC_0$$

and this is what I did:
$$C=KC_0$$  $$K\frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{d}= {K}C_{0}$$ $$\frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{d}= C_{0}$$

However, the answer to the equation only led us back to the first $C_0$ above and the result of the first trial $$Trial_1 = 0.22pF$$  (where  $K = 1$, $A = 200.3mm^2$, $d = 8.1mm$, and $\varepsilon_{0} = 8.85$).

---

Sorry for the really messing formatting. I suck at it.

Is this **right**? I can't bring myself to trust my intuition and my understanding about the lab work. I also assume that what I did is wrong because it kept giving me literally 0% percentage error, and I am not really sure if I'm on the right path.